# OMNET++ tk-gui wrong icon placement

Tags: tk-toolkit, omnet++, veins, sumo

I am working with Artery / VEINS (I do not think this matters) and SUMO and OMNET++ :)

As you can see, my OMNET TK-GUI is no longer showing my network correctly, all icons are in the same place!

**The World.ned**
[image: The World.ned]
**TK-GUI showing wrong**
[image: TK-GUI showing wrong]

Two days ago, this was not happening, I could see the vehicles moving around the OMNET TK-GUI.

So, what have I done? I installed the new NVIDIA driver but I do not think this affects.

Any suggestion? :) Have a really nice day!

Comment: Can you try removing the `.tkenvrc` file in your simulation's directory? Maybe some weird settings have been stored there.

Comment: Thanks for your time @ChristophSommer. I will give it a try, probably you are correct since now I am using a fresh PC and is showing the nodes again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known issue in Tkenv. For some reason the zoom level gets reset to 0.00x from time to time. Just zoom in (press and hold <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd>) until the network gets magnified to a reasonable size.

Also, please note that Tkenv is getting retired in newer versions of OMNeT++, in favor of the more modern Qtenv interface.